# React Native 0.47.1: Hot reload is not reflecting code changes on MacOS

Tags: ios, macos, react-native

I'm trying to get hot reload working with my React Native project. The packager shows the message `Bundling index.ios.js ... [hmr enabled]` and when I make a change, i see the `Hot reloading...` message flash on the device so I'm confident that the change is being detected.  However, the actual screen is not reflecting the code changes. Live reload works fine.

I've reinstalled the node modules and reset/uninstalled/reinstalled watchman. Nothing seems to have any effect.

What else should I be trying? How do I figure out why the screen isn't being updated?

Comment: Have you tried to clear watchman using `watchman watch-del-all`?

Comment: Tried that now, it says I'm using 4.9.0 and lists my react-native project directory. Still isn't reflecting any changes.

Comment: How about this? `rm -rf /usr/local/var/run/watchman && brew uninstall watchman && brew install watchman`

Comment: Same.  Changes are still not reflected.

Comment: have you try to run your packager using root?

Comment: Are you sure it's not code related?

Comment: I run the build using Xcode, is there some configuration I should look at? How do I know if it is using root when it runs the package manager? And no, I'm not sure it's not code related - is there a list of code related things that prevents hot reloading from working? I saw that the root component can't be a functional component (and it's not) but I don't know of anything else to verify.

Comment: Have you tried to use another device or uninstall the app in the simulator?

Comment: I've tried both the simulator and an actual device, both do the same thing. I tried uninstalling on the device to no avail.

Comment: you can try to run the packager in with command line using npm start, also i if the components or the code you change is not from main scene for example using redux or custom component, the hot reload will not working correctly. I think the hot reload is not perfect yet

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting that.  So when people do react native development, do they just use Live reload and re-navigate to the correct screen over and over again? Or do you save the path state and load it on refresh? I'm just trying to figure out how to make it less painful...

Comment: Normaly you can bypass all the screen navigation, i also save the repetitive param like access token on asyncstorage, and hardcode some required parameter. If you are using flux it is a little easier to bypass the scene. But idk its the best practice.

Comment: Are you using Cocoapods?

Comment: No, I'm not using COcoapods

Comment: Okay, is this a new project or updated from a previous RN?

Comment: I was on RN 0.43 then upgraded to 0.47.1 when I couldn't get 0.43 working with hot reload (was hoping they fixed something).

Comment: Is this issue reproducible with a new react-native project? @Bill

Comment: A code example would be very helpful as well.

Answer (score 6):

The current version of hmr in `react-native` only works for components that extend from `React.Component` or `Component` [[see](https://github.com/gaearon/babel-plugin-react-transform/blob/master/src/index.js#L174)]. In other words, it doesn't work for functional components or components that extend another base class.

- For functional components you can use [babel-plugin-functional-hmr](https://github.com/bvic23/babel-plugin-functional-hmr).
- If you have a custom base class, you can override `react-transform` plugin in your `.babelrc` as the following:

  ```
  {
    "presets": ["react-native"],
    "env": {
      "development": {
        "plugins": [
          ["react-transform",
            {
              "transforms": [{
                "transform": "react-transform-hmr",
                "imports": ["react"],
                "locals": ["module"]
              }],
              "superClasses": ["CustomComponent", "React.Component", "Component"]
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: This is particularly useful to those who prefer using React.PureComponent vs React.Component. Thanks

Comment: I've also noticed that if you have rendered code outside of the `render()` method inside your component, it will not hot-reload.

Comment: Rendered outside the render method - do you mean like via function calls that return React components? Or something else?